# Sound is working, but not playing?

Tags: 14.04, sound

Running Ubuntu 14.04. Recently my sound for Youtube, Spotify, VLC etc. stopped working. However, changing the sound makes a little "bleep" noise and going into the test sound from settings works fine, with or without headphones. So all SFX noises are working fine but sound from a program isn't.

I've checked mute buttons, program sound levels in settings, rebooting, and obviously tried many different programs. The problem may have started after using an HDMI hookup. Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Worked it out, using "PulseAudio Volume Control" (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`) and changing the output sources from HDMI to internal analog. Not sure why these weren't showing up in system settings...

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides all that is listed in [Ubuntu's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) own troubleguide, have checked where your sound output is?

Go to sound settings, see if you have more then built-in audio. 
check Alsa mixer by going to the terminal and type **alsamixer**. Use the displayed controls to change settings to that all are on your sound card.

Comment: There output is correct. Ahhh yes, AlsaMixer is listing the active soundcard as an  HDMI unit (Card: HDMI). Pressing F6 lets me highlight "HDA Intel PCH" which has a mixer for speaker, headphones etc, but it isn't clear how to switch to this card (pressing enter/F6 again doesn't seem to work). This seems to be the issue though.  Any hints?